# Mongoose keeps trying to authenticate with wrong admin db even though it is specified

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session, connect-mongo

The initial connection to the database seems to authenticate fine with this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost/traderdb/?authSource=admin', {
    auth: {
        authdb: "admin"
    }
    }, function(e) {
        //other things
});
```

After that however, when I try to create a new session and authenticate the user everything crashes and in the mongo logs I can see that the application tried to authenticate with mongodb using the `traderdb` database and not the admin database, even though I have authSource set correctly and it connects fine the first time with the same URI.

This is where I initialize the session store. This is placed inside the callback of the `mongoose.connect` call.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secrettexthere',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: 'mongodb://user:pass@localhost/traderdb/?authSource=admin',
        db: 'traderdb',
        collection: 'sessions',
        auto_reconnect: true
    })
}));
```

Nothing fails on application startup, and the mongo logs confirm that a connection was successfully made and authenticated with the admin database. After that however, when I try to actually use the session store the application crashes with the error `Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions`. And in the mongo server logs I can see that my application tried connecting and authenticating with `traderdb` instead of `admin` as the authentication source.

Comment: You haven't mentioned DB port in this code

Comment: @machadevendher I'm just using the default port. It connects fine, this is an authentication issue.